# PHP-MySQL merge many query into one query to execution fast

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have PHP script to add new record and check this record in `table1`,`table2` and `table3` if record not exist than add it into `table3` else update the record to `table1` or `table2` (where its exist).

I have large data to check. So its possible to perform this task using single MySQL query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to take a look at triggers...

Comment: And What have you tried so far

Comment: better show some code

Comment: try using union all or join in this case..

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind, that joining two large tables may be a lot slower than using 2 or 3 separate query to get data out of them one by one. The main question is what you consider huge. Joining millions of rows is never a good idea in MySQL AFAIK if you have large rows.

So while having it done in one query is definitely possible it may not be the economical thing to do.

We also need some info about row sizes, indexes, basic query syntax and stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I want to make it faster so i am trying to get it all by using single query, but its slow so i don't want to use in in single query.